# not able to retrieve session attributes when i navigate through JSP pages

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

i am  working on eclipse juno and apache server.
 I have 3 pages:

- login.jsp(this page is then redirected to servlet(Validation.java) for login authentication if valid then navigate to search.jsp)
- search.jsp
- fill.jsp
   
  i have set values of session variables in Validation.java like this 

   `String s_user=request.getParameter("n_user");

   HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);

   session.setAttribute("ses_user",s_user);`
   
  and printed values like this :
   
      `String s =(String)session.getAttribute("ses_user");
      System.out.println(s);`
   
  and printed values of session on every page but every time when i navigate through these pages it create new **sessionID** .

i have checked it through

```
System.out.println("session ID"+request.getSession(false));
```

why i am not getting same session ID nor getting the reason for same?

login.jsp:

```
<form name="loginform" method="post" action="Validation"  >
    <br><br>
    <table width="300px" align="center" style="background-color:#C1CDCD;">
        <tr><td colspan=2></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan=2> </td></tr>
        <tr>
         <td><b><font color="#00008B">Login Name</font></b></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="n_user" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b><font color="#00008B">Password</font></b></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="n_pass" value=""></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validate()"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <td colspan=2> </td></tr>
    </table>


</form>
```

Comment: I think you need to get session user not session id

Comment: @MohammodHossain: yes session value i want to retrieve.

Comment: could  you show your  html code?

Comment: do you have cookies disabled in your browser

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println("session ID" + (String)(request.getSession().getAttribute("ses_user")));`

You will get you attribute value set in session. `SessionId` gets changed because after validation you create new session.

Answer (score 0):

```
     //set session  
    HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("ses_user",s_user); 

        // get session

  String userid = (String)session.getAttribute("ses_user");
if(userid  != null){
// do something
}
```

Comment: i have done the same but not able to retrieve value of session on fill.jsp or on search.jsp

Comment: are you sure, s_user is not null? add <%@ page language="java" session="true"%>

Comment: i have added this <%@ page language="java" session="true"%> to my login.jsp only..but still same probs

Comment: i have nothing much on fill.jsp but me jst printing session value of user

Answer (score 0):

you should just use `HttpSession session=request.getSession()` without boolean parameter.

`session=request.getSession()` is same as `session=request.getSession(true)`

Comment: what's wrong with that?... it will create new session for every new user who login

Comment: yes it will create new session, for  every new user. Also please see if you have cookies disabled in your browser

Comment: i have checked default browser setting and also has enabled my cookie..nt no hope

Comment: what is the output of this `String s =(String)session.getAttribute("ses_user"); System.out.println(s); `

Comment: this if i print on Validation.java.. it is displaying correctly..bt if i print it on search.jsp or fill.jsp it is printing NULL

Comment: also can you try `System.out.println("session ID"+request.getSession(false).getId());` which is defined in servlet spec. There is no contract on how toString() should behave

Comment: it is because new session id is created on every page i navigate.. how to avoid that?

Comment: my rule is that I always use `request.getSession()` you should avoid using boolean arguments, can you try that and let me know. In my test no new sessions are created in each pages.

Comment: hey using System.out.println("session ID"+request.getSession(false).getId()); i printed it on validaton.java and search.jsp i am able to get same id but not getting on fill.jsp

Comment: what is the output if you try without boolean argument. use this `System.out.println("session ID"+request.getSession().getId()); `

Comment: i am getting different ID on fill.jsp

Comment: cant guess the reason anymore, i will need to see the source. also please try some other browsers, i strongly suspect it could be your browser.

Comment: ok will let u know if any browser problem..but i have made another project it is running fine and giving same session id..